# Set time to update location in Google Map Android

Tags: android, google-maps, location

I am using Google Map in my app to update location in a time. Follow Google Map document, I use setInterval(TIME_UPDATE) to set time to update location. The problem here is the time I set and the time to response the location update from Google map are not the same. In my code,  I set time is 1 second( setInterval(1000) ) but the Google Map update my location after 5 second (I'm indoor). When I am outdoor, the Google Map update correctly. Here is my code:

```
private void makeLocationRequest(long secondUpdateLocation) {

    REQUEST = LocationRequest.create().setInterval(1000) // set time to update
            .setFastestInterval(1000) // set time to update
            .setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY);
    LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.requestLocationUpdates(mGoogleApiClient, REQUEST,
                                                             this); // LocationListener
}
```

Anyone can help me?? Thks a lot :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As from the documentation, that value is not a "Have to" but just an inexact value:
https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/location/LocationRequest.html#setInterval(long)

> Set the desired interval for active location updates, in milliseconds.
>
> The location client will actively try to obtain location updates for
>   your application at this interval, so it has a direct influence on the
>   amount of power used by your application. Choose your interval wisely.
>
> This interval is inexact. You may not receive updates at all (if no
>   location sources are available), or you may receive them slower than
>   requested. You may also receive them faster than requested (if other
>   applications are requesting location at a faster interval). The
>   fastest rate that that you will receive updates can be controlled with
>   setFastestInterval(long). By default this fastest rate is 6x the
>   interval frequency.
>
> Applications with only the coarse location permission may have their
>   interval silently throttled.
>
> An interval of 0 is allowed, but not recommended, since location
>   updates may be extremely fast on future implementations.

So there is no warranties the updates are coming at your requested rate, especially indoor, the GPS is not fully working and hence could be slower to get updates (in some cases, in indoor you don't even get updates).